# Kendo Grid changing datasource on button click on mvc wrapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to change a kendo datasource and change the whole grid content in the same partial view?? Please any idea about it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#yourButtonId").click(function() {
  $("#yourChartId").data("kendoChart").dataSource.read(yourNewDataSourceReader);
});
```

Hope this helps, have a nice day,

Alberto

Comment: fyi if your using a kendo Grid control instead it would be `....data("kendoGrid")`

Comment: Thanks for your contribution

Comment: I already solved the problem for the grid, now im having the same problem with a combobox, any help??